# Windows 7 - User-specific %PATH%

Tags: windows-7, windows, path, environment-variables

I'd like to set up a system for Windows 7 where each user has their own private directory in %PATH%.  I tried setting %PATH% to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Bin;%SystemRoot%\System32;[...]` but it doesn't seem to work.

For those who don't realize what I'm trying to do, it's sort of like `EXPORT PATH=~/bin` would be on *nix.  It can be on a user specific basis if need be (and that would actually be prefer to the machine-wide settings).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to modify the system path so it's dynamic per-user.

You can set environment variables on a per-user basis, so this isn't necessary.

via the registry;

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

via the ui;

[image: UI screenshot]

Admittedly such an approach falls down once you add more users, but on a home system this probably isn't a frequent occurrence.

Comment: You can add the variables on the per-user basis, but will this override the system %PATH%?

Comment: It will add to the system path.

Comment: There are two problems with this method.  First, as you stated, it's impractical on a system with more users.  The second problem is that the `PATH` variable, unlike other variables, is [appended to the system path](https://diigo.com/01i09s).  It looks like there's no way to set system variables in a dynamic way :(  This also answers @MiffTheFox 's question.

Comment: @Ghodmode You can simply set the user's `PATH` to something like `%PATH%;C:\your\path` : On Win 7, the variables are expanded and my path is appended to the system's path. Also, you can run `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` to show the dialog. I haven't tested on other versions, though.